# VB script + delete files that contain word and older then X month

Tags: vba, vbscript

the following VB script , will remove the files under Temp dir and contain the word **access.log**

how to change this VB script in order to remove only files that contain the word "access.log" and are old then 1  or 2 or 3 ... month

I want to add in the VB some parameter that will contain the month Number
and the files will be deleted according to this parameter

for example if **Month_do_del=12**

Then only files that contain **access.log** that old then 12 month will be deleted

```
   If LCase(Right(Wscript.FullName, 11)) = "wscript.exe" Then
     strPath = Wscript.ScriptFullName
     strCommand = "%comspec% /k cscript  """ & strPath & """"
     Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
     objShell.Run(strCommand), 1, True
     Wscript.Quit
 End If

Set objNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
strLog = "Files deleted on " & objNetwork.ComputerName & " at " & Now &    VbCrLf & "===================================================="
  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFilesToDelete = ""
ShowSubFolders objFSO.GetFolder("G:\Temp")
 If InStr(strFilesToDelete, "|") > 0 Then
arrFiles = Split(strFilesToDelete, "|")
For Each strFilePath In arrFiles
    DeleteFile strFilePath
Next
  ElseIf strFilesToDelete <> "" Then
DeleteFile strFilesToDelete
  Else
WScript.Echo "No files were found."
strLog = strLog & VbCrLf & "No files were found."
 End If

 Set objLogFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("C:\FileDeletionLog.log", True)
 objLogFile.Write strLog
 objLogFile.Close
 Set objLogFile = Nothing

  Sub ShowSubFolders(Folder)
On Error Resume Next
For Each objFile In Folder.Files
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        WScript.Echo "Error reading " & Folder.Path
           strLog = strLog & VbCrLf & "Error reading " &    Folder.Path
        Err.Clear
        On Error Resume Next
        Exit For
     Else
        On Error GoTo 0
             If Instr(UCase(objFile.Name), UCase  ("access.log"))     Then
            If strFilesToDelete = "" Then
                strFilesToDelete = objFile.Path
            Else
                        strFilesToDelete =    strFilesToDelete & "|" & objFile.Path
            End If
        End If
    End If
   Next
    For Each Subfolder in Folder.SubFolders
    ShowSubFolders Subfolder
  Next
  End Sub




  Sub DeleteFile(strFilePath)
On Error Resume Next
WScript.Echo "Deleting " & strFilePath
objFSO.DeleteFile strFilePath, True
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "Could not delete " & strFilePath
    strLog = strLog & VbCrLf & "Could not delete " & strFilePath
    Err.Clear
    On Error GoTo 0
Else
    On Error GoTo 0
        strLog = strLog & VbCrLf & "Successfully deleted " & strFilePath
 End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if `FileDateTime`, `Date` and `DateDiff` are supported in VBS. If not you can easily port your VBS code to VBA. DateDiff will find the difference between two dates in months.

```
Function CheckMonths(nMonths As Integer, fPath As String) As Boolean
    CheckMonths = False
    If DateDiff("m", FileDateTime(fPath), Date) = nMonths Then
        CheckMonths = True
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: thx Jeanno please advice - where I can add you code in my script?

Comment: `If Instr(1, UCase(objFile.Name), UCase("access.log")) And CheckMonths(3,objFile.Name)  Then`

Comment: first I +1 for you -  Another rlittle quastion if for example I want to delete some files that contain the access.log and VAR.log and ddd.log then how to put these files in the ( ..... ) , I try ("access.log VAR.log ddd.log") but its not work ?

Comment: You will need to use the `Or` operator so something like `If (Instr(1, UCase(objFile.Name), UCase("access.log")) Or Instr(1, UCase(objFile.Name), UCase("VAR.log")) Or Instr(1, UCase(objFile.Name), UCase("ddd.log"))) And And CheckMonths(3,objFile.Name) ThenCheckMonths(3,objFile.Name) Then`

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
If Instr(UCase(objFile.Name), UCase  ("access.log"))     Then
```

to this

```
If Instr(1, UCase(objFile.Name), UCase("access.log")) And DateDiff("m", objFile.DateLastModified, Date) >= 12 Then
```

Comment: first I +1 for you - Another rlittle quastion if for example I want to delete some files that contain the access.log and VAR.log and ddd.log then how to put these files in the ( ..... ) , I try ("access.log VAR.log ddd.log") but its not work ?